# Python re regex matching issue

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, expression

Ok please be gentle - this is my first stackoverflow question and I've struggled with this for a few hours. I'm sure the answer is something obvious, staring me in the face but I give up.

I'm trying to grab an element from a webpage (ie determine gender of a name) from a name website.

The python code I've written is here:

```
import re
import urllib2

response=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.behindthename.com/name/janet")
html=response.read()
print html

patterns = ['Masculine','Feminine']

for pattern in patterns:
print "Looking for %s in %s<<<" % (pattern,html)

    if re.findall(pattern,html):
        print "Found a match!"
        exit
    else:
        print "No match!"
```

When I dump html I see Feminine there, but the re.findall isn't matching. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know that with such simple regex you can just do `if pattern in html`?

Comment: Other answers notwithstanding, I don't see any reason why your code as given won't actually work. What do you get if you `print re.findall(pattern, html)` in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

[Do not parse an HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use a specialized tool - an HTML parser.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.behindthename.com/name/janet'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

print soup.select('div.nameinfo span.info')[0].text  # prints "Feminine"
```

---

Or, you can [find an element by text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument):

```
gender = soup.find(text='Feminine')
```

And then, see if it is `None` (not found) or not: `gender is None`.

Comment: @alecxe yes, the top answer in that link was very clear and easy to understand. No confusion at all. (I'm bookmarking that for later use.)